# Resize (shrink) a ctypes array

Tags: python, arrays, resize, ctypes

Let's say I have a 10 element array:

```
from ctypes import *
arr = c_float * 10
```

, and I'd like to shrink it to 5 elements. I tried doing something like this:

```
resize(arr, sizeof(c_float) * 5)
arr = (c_float * 5).from_address(addressof(arr))
```

But I get a `ValueError: minimum size is XXX` exception meaning that I can't shrink the memory, only grow it. If I really want, is it possible to overcome this limitation with a clever hack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work just fine:

```
>>> float_10 = c_float * 10
>>> float_5 = c_float * 5
>>> a1 = float_10(range(10))
>>> a2 = float_5.from_address(addressof(a1))
>>> print list(a1)
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
>>> print list(a2)
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

EDIT: This doesn't actually resize the original list though, and `addressof(a1)` will equal `addressof(a2)`, so the unused bits of the list linger in memory...

Comment: This is actually what I have now, I save the `actual_size` and only resize if growing.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there's any safe way to shrink the array without copying the data...

Answer (score 2):

The native C function `realloc` allows for memory shrinkage. This is probably unsafe, but actually frees the memory after the array is resized:

```
from ctpyes import *
clib = CDLL("libc.so.6")

bigarr = (c_float * 10)(*range(10)) # some data
smallarr = (c_float * 5).from_buffer(bigarr) # no copies here

# free unneeded memory
clib.realloc(bigarr, sizeof(smallarr))

# finally, delete the bigarr python object because occasional
# use of its truncated elements may cause segfault.
del bigarr
```

I tested this with 100 000 000 float array to see if the memory was actually released.

**UPD:** As pointed out by AKX (also covered here: [Is realloc guaranteed to be in-place when the buffer is shrinking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162502/is-realloc-guaranteed-to-be-in-place-when-the-buffer-is-shrinking)), this approach does not guarantee that the return of the `realloc` will point to the same memory location as original array used to, although it was always the case in my practice.

Comment: @GiovanniFunchal, doesn't this answer you question?

Comment: Aren't you are supposed to look at the return value of `realloc` to see if it moved your buffer while resizing it? In addition I guess there's no guarantee that Python even uses the libc memory allocator (could use jemalloc or whatever), so `realloc` might wreak absolute havoc on the buffer... *shrug* :)

Comment: @AKX, I tested this several times and ``realloc`` always returned the same value as ``addressof`` of bigarr and smallarr. It'll return another pointer if it can't get around resizing the original array. I think shrinking the array should always be possible without moving, since no more memory is required.

Comment: It _should_, yeah, but the specification for `realloc` says it will return the new position, so it's allowed to do that.

Comment: @AKX, you're right. Just for curiosity, do you know any cases where ``clib.realloc`` will move the data while shrinking?

Comment: In practice? No. But this might be deployed on a system with an allocator in libc that always moves data when `realloc`ing, for instance, so it's not safe to just assume this. Unless you know the behavior of the allocator on the target platform, of course, and can make the assumption.